# Netbook/Tablet : is there a way to switch between Desktop mode and touch mode (preferably the new Touch interface of Ubuntu)?

Tags: unity, dell, ubuntu-netbook, inspiron, tablet

I have a Dell Inspiron Duo (a netbook with flipping screen that functions as a tablet as well) ... and to revive this netbook/tablet I installed Ubuntu (13.10).

Everything seems to work just fine (in desktop mode) but I would like to switch to the Touch-interface once the screen gets flipped.

I read an article on the dell inspiron duo that does this (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1658635) but ... I like the new touch-interface for ubuntu unity so much ... I would like to use that ...

Is there a way to install it and have it behave as I described above ?

(please use descriptive explanations as I am almost a newbie on Linux)

Thanks all.

Comment: are you still using the 2760p with Ubuntu? I use a combination of Windows 7 and Ubuntu, as the there is no Linux Drivers for the finger print reader, so Windows is used to handle the Bios bio-metrics for securing the boot process via the HP-Tools. Just an FYI tip... 
Let me know if need any other help with that machine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would be able to use the project https://launchpad.net/magick-rotation

though I do not have a Dell Inspiron Duo rather I am using a HP EliteBook 2760p and have successfully used that project to run shell scripts from which point one could script what ever they wanted including calls to existing programs.

As for the touch interface, "[Ubuntu Touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices)" is mostly for phones but you have a tablet pc...unsure the complexity of switching between the "Unity" and the "Touch" interface...

Though to the point of scripting the screen rotation you can find the following example [here](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Tablet_PC_Setup#Tablet_PC_Automatic_Rotation_Script)

```
#!/bin/bash

old="0"
while true; do
    if [[ -e /sys/devices/platform/hp-wmi/tablet ]]; then
        new=`cat /sys/devices/platform/hp-wmi/tablet`
        if [[ $new != $old ]]; then
            if [[ $new == "0" ]]; then
                echo "Rotate to landscape, hide CellWriter."
                xrandr -o normal
                xsetwacom set stylus rotate none
                xsetwacom set eraser rotate none
                xsetwacom set touch rotate none
                cellwriter --hide-window
            elif [[ $new == "1" ]]; then
                echo "Rotate to portrait, show CellWriter."
                xrandr -o right
                xsetwacom set stylus rotate cw
                xsetwacom set eraser rotate cw
                xsetwacom set touch rotate cw
                cellwriter --show-window
            fi
        fi
        old=$new
        sleep 1s
    fi
done

# From Red_Lion post #576:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=845911&p=7732316
```

There is a poject called [desktop-switcher](https://launchpad.net/desktop-switcher/) which has an non maintained "[sourced code base](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~netbook-remix-team/desktop-switcher/trunk/files)" which might be helpful if you want to do more than scripting as suggested above...